# Haskell: acid-state over multiple files?

Tags: haskell, acid-state

I have a file structure like this:

```
--- Database.hs ---
data Database = ...
...

--- User.hs ---
import Database
addUser :: Update Database ()
...

--- Post.hs
import Database
addPost :: Update Database ()
...
```

The problem is that I need to called `makeAcidic ''Database [...]` in both `User.hs` and `Post.hs` to make their functions acidic, but `makeAcidic` at the same time generate `IsAcidic` instances for `Database` so GHC complains about duplicate instance declarations.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so I figure it out. Just separate the definition with the Template Haskell:

```
--- Database/Types.hs ---
data Database = ...
...

--- Database.hs ---
import Database.Types
import User
import Post
makeAcidic ''Database [addUser, addPost]

--- User.hs ---
import Database.Types
addUser :: Update Database ()
...

--- Post.hs ---
import Database.Types
addPost :: Update Database ()
...
```